# Compile error on QuickBlox iOS SDK (v1.5.1)

Tags: quickblox

Download the latest QuickBlox iOS SDK (v1.5.1) and tried to compile and run the sample chat example, failed to compiled with multiple issues.
I assume the Sample Chat project (called supersimple) to work out-of-the-box but unfortunately no...

Issue #1:
ld: library not found for -lxml2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Issue #2:
fatal error: file '//quickblox-ios-sdk-master-1.5.1/sample-chat/../Framework/Quickblox.framework/Headers/RatingsService/RatingsServiceFramework.h' has been modified since the precompiled header was built

For issue #2, I did tried to do clean build folder (option+shift+cmd+K) and rebuilt, didn't work.

I'm using XCode 4.6.1 on Mac OSX 10.8.3.

Comment: not sure this question belongs here.

Comment: what do you mean? I followed the instruction from QuickBlox to post it here: "StackOverflow — we will be happy to solve your issue if you ask ‘quickblox’ tagged question on StackOverflow." See http://quickblox.com/contact. Unless QuickBlox is not supposed to do so...

Comment: What sample do you use? Do you use samples from this repo https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk ?
Or something else?

Comment: @EvanK That's why I said "not sure", just to take attention of relevant-people to review question. It doesn't look (to me) as problem with specific part of code you need help with. Not sure so I didn't take any action against question, that's all m8. Btw, welcome to StackOverflow, hope you can find what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, guys, for the quick response. Yeah, I'm new to stackoverflow, pardon me if my question is not clear or something. @IgorKhomenko yes, I use the samples from the git repo, the SimpleSample-chat users-ios in specific: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat

Comment: Could you send screenshot with you error please

Comment: The problem seems to go away after I restart my Macbook. Not sure exactly why it happened, could be due to some previous erroneous state in XCode by this or other projects I have. Anyway, I'm able to build the SimpleSample-chat project right out-of-the-box. Thanks for the help and sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: great, you can close your question

Comment: They could have changed or removed the app from database, so the App ID, Secret and etc are not evaluating. Create your own APP, copy the ID, Secret, etc, paste on the code and try again ! Tell us what happened...